# Show that the second fundamental form of a surface remains unchanged under change of parametrization

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Show that the second fundamental form of a surface remains unchanged under a change of parametrization.

---

I know the solution for the first fundamental form. But I cannot show this please help. Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of "second fundamental form"?

Comment: $Ldu^2+2Mdudv+Ndv^2$ @JesseMadnick

Comment: Should not be "isometries" instead of parametrization? For example, the first fundamental form is invariant under isometries. Could you please check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\langle N(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle=0$ by differentiating we have $\langle N'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle+\langle N(s),\alpha''(s)\rangle=0$. Now we have:

$$\begin{align}
II_p(\alpha'(p)) & = -\langle dN_p(\alpha'(p)),\alpha'(p)\rangle \\
 & = -\langle N'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle=\langle N(s),\alpha''(s)\rangle\\ 
 & =\langle N,k\overrightarrow{n}\rangle_p=k_n(p). \\
\end{align}$$

Which is independent from change of parametrization.
ref: `Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces Manfredo P. do carmo`